# Beautfiul Soup return empty list when scraping YouTube chanel

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, youtube

I am trying to use this code to get some public information about youtube channel (API not suits well this task).

Example of code:

```
import re
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://www.youtube.com/c/Rozziofficial/about"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(URL).content, "html.parser")

# We locate the JSON data using a regular-expression pattern
data = re.search(r"var ytInitialData = ({.*});", str(soup)).group(1)

# Uncomment to view all the data
# print(json.dumps(data))

# This converts the JSON data to a python dictionary (dict)
json_data = json.loads(data)

# This is the info from the webpage on the right-side under "stats", it contains the data you want
stats = json_data["contents"]["twoColumnBrowseResultsRenderer"]["tabs"][5]["tabRenderer"]["content"]["sectionListRenderer"]["contents"][0]["itemSectionRenderer"]["contents"][0]["channelAboutFullMetadataRenderer"]

print("Channel Views:", stats["viewCountText"]["simpleText"])
print("Joined:", stats["joinedDateText"]["runs"][1]["text"])
```

Expected result (6 month ago it works well):

```
Joined: Jun 30, 2007
```

.
.
But now got:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

traceback shows the error is on this row:

```
data = re.search(r"var ytInitialData = ({.*});", str(soup)).group(1)
```

Can you help to fix this that this code continues work and return data?

Any help is appreciated,
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is working fine

```
import re
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://www.youtube.com/c/Rozziofficial/about"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(URL).content, "html.parser")

# We locate the JSON data using a regular-expression pattern
data = re.search(r"var ytInitialData = ({.*});", str(soup)).group(1)

# Uncomment to view all the data
# print(json.dumps(data))

# This converts the JSON data to a python dictionary (dict)
json_data = json.loads(data)

# This is the info from the webpage on the right-side under "stats", it contains the data you want
stats = json_data["contents"]["twoColumnBrowseResultsRenderer"]["tabs"][5]["tabRenderer"]["content"]["sectionListRenderer"]["contents"][0]["itemSectionRenderer"]["contents"][0]["channelAboutFullMetadataRenderer"]

print("Channel Views:", stats["viewCountText"]["simpleText"])
print("Joined:", stats["joinedDateText"]["runs"][1]["text"])
```

Output:

```
Channel Views: 1,12,94,125টি ভিউ
Joined: 30 জুন, 2007
```

Comment: thanks! Seems it depends on ip address you are requesting from. Change my VPN location and it is also works fine..

Comment: Yes, something that types of bugs may happen. Your code is 100% accurate and this the perfect way to scrape data from youTube as they use api and data is also in DOM as json format in script so the the best solution is re or api. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're not actually using BeautifulSoup at all here.  You're just fetching the raw text and searching it for a string.

This is the problem with web scraping.  YouTube has changed their JavaScript, and that variable no longer exists.  We don't know what you are trying to find, but your current method isn't going to work.  You may actually need to use Selenium to run the Javascript and pull the info from the DOM.